# Fixing a function checking whether the input binary tree is ordered

Tags: function, sorting, haskell, functional-programming, binary-tree

I have the following algebraic data type:

```
data Tree a = Empty | Node a (Tree a) (Tree a)
  deriving (Show, Eq)
```

Also, I have this code snippet:

```
fromJust :: Maybe a -> a
fromJust (Just val) = val
fromJust Nothing = error "Cannot unpack Nothing."

getTreeMinimum :: Ord a => Tree a -> Maybe a
getTreeMaximum :: Ord a => Tree a -> Maybe a

getTreeMaximum Empty = Nothing
getTreeMaximum (Node value l r) =
  if l == Empty && r == Empty then Just value else
  if l == Empty && r /= Empty then if value < fromJust (getTreeMinimum r) then (getTreeMaximum r) else
  if l /= Empty && r == Empty then if fromJust (getTreeMaximum l) < value then Just (value) else
  if l /= Empty && r /= Empty then if fromJust (getTreeMaximum l) < value && value < fromJust (getTreeMinimum r) then (getTreeMaximum r) else Nothing

getTreeMinimum Empty = Nothing
getTreeMinimum (Node value l r) = 
  if l == Empty && r == Empty then Just value else
  if l == Empty && r /= Empty then if value < fromJust (getTreeMinimum r) then Just (value) else
  if l /= Empty && r == Empty then if fromJust (getTreeMaximum l) < value then (getTreeMinimum l)
  if l /= Empty && r /= Empty then if fromJust (getTreeMaximum l) < value && value < fromJust (getTreeMinimum r) then (getTreeMinimum l) else Nothing

isOrderedHelper :: Ord a => Tree a -> Bool
isOrderedHelper Empty = True

isOrderedHelper (Node nodeValue leftChild Empty) = if isOrderedHelper leftChild == False then False else (fromJust (getTreeMaximum leftChild)) < nodeValue

isOrderedHelper (Node nodeValue Empty rightChild) = if isOrderedHelper rightChild == False then False else nodeValue < fromJust ((getTreeMinimum rightChild))

isOrderedHelper (Node nodeValue leftChild rightChild) =
  if isOrderedHelper leftChild == False || isOrderedHelper rightChild == False
  then False 
  else fromJust (getTreeMaximum leftChild) < nodeValue && nodeValue < fromJust (getTreeMinimum rightChild)

isOrdered :: Ord a => Tree a -> Bool
isOrdered Empty = True
isOrdered tree = isOrderedHelper tree
```

The above gives me:

```
error: parse error on input 'getTreeMinimum'
    getTreeMinimum Empty = Nothing
    ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
Failed, no modules loaded.
```

I have two questions (the second one is optional):

1. How to fix the compile time error?
2. Is it possible to improve the efficiency of the function in question?

Comment: I think you're missing a few `else`s in `if l /= Empty && r /= Empty then if fromJust (getTreeMaximum l) < value && value < fromJust (getTreeMinimum r) then (getTreeMaximum r) else Nothing`

Comment: Note that it's very common in programming languages, when the compiler signals a syntax error on a line, that your actual error was on the line before that. Here, your error is the missing `else`s; the compiler only notices the error when it encounters the next line, expecting it to start with `else`, and noticing it doesn't start with `else`.

Comment: Notes: `e == False` is the same as `not e`; `if not e1 then False else e2` is the same as `e1 && e2`; `if e1 then False else e2` is the same as `(not e1) && e2`; `if not e1 || not e2 then False else e3 && e4`  is the same as `e1 && e2 && e3 && e4`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Since `if` is an expression in Haskell each `if` has to have exatly one `then` and one `else` but this

```hs
getTreeMaximum (Node value l r) =
  if l == Empty && r == Empty then Just value else
  if l == Empty && r /= Empty then if value < fromJust (getTreeMinimum r) then (getTreeMaximum r) else
  if l /= Empty && r == Empty then if fromJust (getTreeMaximum l) < value then Just (value) else
  if l /= Empty && r /= Empty then if fromJust (getTreeMaximum l) < value && value < fromJust (getTreeMinimum r) then (getTreeMaximum r) else Nothing
```

has 7 `if` and 7 `then`
but only 4 `else`

I would probably write that using pattern matching to avoid such a deeply nested `if` tree:

```hs
getTreeMaximum (Node value Empty Empty) = Just value
getTreeMaximum (Node value Empty r) = if value < fromJust (getTreeMinimum r) then (getTreeMaximum r) else Nothing
getTreeMaximum (Node value l Empty) = if fromJust (getTreeMaximum l) < value then Just (value) else Nothing
getTreeMaximum (Node value l r) = if fromJust (getTreeMaximum l) < value && value < fromJust (getTreeMinimum r) then (getTreeMaximum r) else Nothing
```

But I don't think the clauses other than the `getTreeMaximum Empty` have any reason to return `Nothing` at all since there's always a `value`, so you'll have to adjust these.

Answer (score 1):

An efficiency tip: you don't need to compute the maximum and minimum to check whether a tree is sorted. You can more directly check it as follows.

Define a function `sortedAndWithin tree lowerBound upperBound` that checks that `tree` is sorted, and that all its values are between the bounds.

Leaves are trivial to handle: they are always sorted.

Instead a `Node value left right` is sorted and within the bounds iff:

- the value is within the bounds
- the `left` subtree is within the *new* bounds ... and ...
- the `right` subtree is within the *new* bounds ... and ...

This recursion makes a single pass on the whole tree.

Initially, you want to set the bounds to "-infinity" and "+infinity". There are several ways to achieve that in Haskell. A suboptimal but still working method is to find the tree minimum and the tree maximum and use those as the starting bounds. Note that in this way the algorithm computes the min/max only once, instead of doing so at each recursion step.