# A function for checking whether a binary tree is sorted - Trying to unwrap a Nothing

Tags: haskell

I have this algebraic data type:

```
data Tree a = Empty | Node a (Tree a) (Tree a)
  deriving (Show, Eq)
```

My function for checking whether the input binary tree is ordered:

```
fromJust :: Maybe a -> a
fromJust (Just val) = val
fromJust Nothing = error "Cannot unpack Nothing."

getTreeMinimum :: Ord a => Tree a -> Maybe a
getTreeMaximum :: Ord a => Tree a -> Maybe a

getTreeMaximum Empty = Nothing
getTreeMaximum (Node value Empty Empty) = Just value
getTreeMaximum (Node value Empty right) = if value < fromJust (getTreeMinimum right) then (getTreeMaximum right) else Nothing
getTreeMaximum (Node value left Empty) = if fromJust (getTreeMaximum left) < value then Just value else Nothing
getTreeMaximum (Node value left right) = if fromJust (getTreeMaximum left) < value && value < fromJust (getTreeMinimum right) then getTreeMaximum right else Nothing

----
getTreeMinimum Empty = Nothing
getTreeMinimum (Node value Empty Empty) = Just value
getTreeMinimum (Node value Empty right) = if value < fromJust (getTreeMinimum right) then Just value else Nothing
getTreeMinimum (Node value left Empty) = if fromJust (getTreeMaximum left) < value then Just value else Nothing
getTreeMinimum (Node value left right) = if fromJust (getTreeMaximum left) < value && value < fromJust (getTreeMinimum right) then getTreeMinimum left else Nothing

isOrderedHelper :: Ord a => Tree a -> Bool
isOrderedHelper Empty = True

isOrderedHelper (Node value l Empty) = if not (isOrderedHelper l) then False else (fromJust (getTreeMaximum l)) < value

isOrderedHelper (Node value Empty r) = if not (isOrderedHelper r) then False else value < fromJust ((getTreeMinimum r))

isOrderedHelper (Node value l r) =
  if not (isOrderedHelper l) || not (isOrderedHelper r)
  then False 
  else fromJust (getTreeMaximum l) < value && value < fromJust (getTreeMinimum r)

isOrdered :: Ord a => Tree a -> Bool
isOrdered Empty = True
isOrdered tree = isOrderedHelper tree
```

Now, when I run:

```
print (isOrdered (Node 1 (Node 0 Empty Empty) (Node 2 Empty Empty)))
```

I get

```
*** Exception: Cannot unpack Nothing.
CallStack (from HasCallStack):
  error, called at Main.hs:...
```

What am I doing wrong here?

Comment: The error comes from the `fromJust` function, which is [partial](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Partial_function), and therefore generally not considered a good idea in Haskell, particularly because it makes it difficult to troubleshoot problems like this one. If possible, try rewriting the code without it, instead relying on pattern-matching.

Comment: I agree with Mark Seemann. Your code actually could be simplified a lot by reordering the logic, using more pattern matching and no `if` checks. However, to debug what you already have, the easiest helper would be to add [`HasCallStack`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.18.0.0/docs/GHC-Stack.html#t:HasCallStack) to your `fromJust` function, so you'll actually be told where the error happens. Or better, simply use [the standard version of `fromJust`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.18.0.0/docs/Data-Maybe.html#v:fromJust).

Comment: As I've put it on your [earlier question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76394660/fixing-a-function-checking-whether-the-input-binary-tree-is-ordered) "the clauses other than the `getTreeMaximum Empty` have [no] reason to return `Nothing` at all since there's always a `value`, so you'll have to adjust these." Especially you have to check the return of your recursive calls instead of blindly applying your `fromJust`, probably something like [`maybe`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.18.0.0/docs/Prelude.html#v:maybe) can help.

Answer (score 2):

Your code has a lot of duplicated patterns introduced by first checking if the node is `Empty` and thus branching a lot. The exact error is likely located in the:

```
isOrderedHelper (Node value l r) =
  if not (isOrderedHelper l) || not (isOrderedHelper r)
  then False 
  else fromJust (getTreeMaximum l) < value && value < fromJust (getTreeMinimum r)
```

If you pass `Node 0 Empty Empty`, then `isOrderedHelper` is both `True` on the two `Empty`s, and you thus perform a `fromJust` on the `getTreeMaximum l`, which will return `Nothing`.

But your code introduces way too much checks. We can simplify this, for example by constructing a small type:

```
data TreeOrder a = Unordered | OrderEmpty | TreeSpan a a deriving (Eq, Show)
```

Here we will return if the tree is `unordered`, empty (`OrderEmpty`) or the minimum and maximum of the tree.

We can mix two of these values with:

```
mixOrder :: Ord a => TreeOrder a -> TreeOrder a -> TreeOrder a
mixOrder Unordered _ = Unordered
mixOrder OrderEmpty x = x
mixOrder _ Unordered = Unordered
mixOrder x OrderEmpty = x
mixOrder (TreeSpan mi1 ma1) (TreeSpan mi2 ma2)
  | ma1 < mi2 = TreeSpan mi1 ma2
  | otherwise = Unordered
```

this is in fact a monoid, with `OrderEmpty` as neutral element, so we can even make this an instance of `Monoid`:

```
instance Ord a => Semigroup (TreeOrder a) where
  (<>) = mixOrder

instance Ord a => Monoid (TreeOrder a) where
  mempty = OrderEmpty
```

We can then thus implement a function for this:

```
treeOrder :: Ord a => Tree a -> TreeOrdered a
treeOrder Empty = OrderEmpty
treeOrder (Node v l r) = treeOrder l <> TreeSpan v v <> treeOrder r

isOrdered :: Ord a => Tree a -> Bool
isOrdered = (/= Unordered) . treeOrder
```

and that is all.

Comment: This task is a course exercise and we are not allowed to do any fancy stuff as `TreeOrder`, etc. :/

Comment: @coderodde: but this is not something builtin, you simply define an extra data type. This is pure "vanilla" Haskell.

Answer (score 2):

As has already been said, your code is simply way too complicated. There's just way too many patterns and `if`s. And the use of a partial function like `fromJust` certainly doesn't help.

Let's take a look at these three equations for `getTreeMaximum`:

```
getTreeMaximum (Node value Empty right) = if value < fromJust (getTreeMinimum right) -- ...
getTreeMaximum (Node value left Empty) = if fromJust (getTreeMaximum left) < value -- ...
getTreeMaximum (Node value left right) = if fromJust (getTreeMaximum left) < value && value < fromJust (getTreeMinimum right) -- ...
```

All of these seem to apply `fromJust` on the result of `getTreeMinimum`/`getTreeMaximum` applied to the branches of the tree.

Let's ask a simple question: is it okay to use `fromJust`, a partial function, in here? Is there any justification for it?

I assume that the way you justified it is very simple - in all of these three cases, the tree that we're applying `getTreeMinimum`/`getTreeMaximum` to is not `Empty` and therefore must have a minimum and a maximum, i.e. these functions must return a `Just` and thus the use of `fromJust` is okay.

That's sound logic. However, the rest of the code doesn't support this. Let's take a look at the same three equations, but lets focus on the very far right of them:

```
getTreeMaximum (Node value Empty right) = ... else Nothing
getTreeMaximum (Node value left Empty) = ... else Nothing
getTreeMaximum (Node value left right) = ... else Nothing
```

Yes, these all seem to be able to return `Nothing`, even though they've been applied to a `Node` and not to an `Empty`. `getTreeMinimum` contains a similar error.

So maybe it would be enough to fix these issues? Maybe, but I'm honestly not sure - as I said, the code is way too complex to understand and there could be other issues. And I'm way too lazy to try fixing it.

However, why don't we simplify the code? First of all, I think that we need to ask different questions here. Instead of asking a tree what it's minimum and maximum are, let's ask something else - are you ordered and do you fit within some given bounds?

Now that just sounds like a more complicated version of the original question. However, it actually makes stuff easier, as it makes the recursive step (which we're obviously going to need since we're working with a recursive structure) fairly trivial.

Why? Perhaps think of it this way - a typical recursive algorithm has some bases cases, which stop the recursion, and the recursive cases, where the algorithm applies itself (perhaps slightly modified) to a part of the original structure. Can we do that with `isOrdered`? Eh, not really - applying `isOrdered` to the branches of a tree doesn't help that much, we need to somehow ensure that the values of the branches lie entirely to the right or left of the node we're currently on, which `isOrdered` doesn't do. You tried doing that with `getTreeMaximum` and `getTreeMinimum`, which then call each other and the recursion gets complicated. I think that we can do better - if we can ask a node if it's ordered and within some bounds, then surely we can tighten those bounds as we walk deeper through the tree, right?

So, let's start with something simple. Our function signature will be:

```
isOrderedAndBounded :: Ord a => a -> a -> Tree a -> Bool
```

It takes the bounds (low and high, assuming low < high) and a tree and returns the answer as a `Bool`.

The base case is trivial, an empty tree is ordered and fits within any bounds:

```
isOrderedAndBounded _ _ Empty = True
```

The other case is a bit more complicated, so let's define it first and then we'll walk through it:

```
isOrderedAndBounded lo hi (Node x l r) =
  lo < x && x < hi && isOrderedAndBounded lo x l && isOrderedAndBounded x hi r
```

A non-empty node is ordered and bounded when the following holds:

- its value is within the bounds - we check that with `lo < x && x < hi`
- its left branch is within the bounds and to the left of its value - since we know that its value is also within the bounds, we can simply check that the left branch is within the bounds given by the current low bound and the value of the node we're on - so we check this with `isOrderedAndBounded lo x l`
- analogously for the right branch, checked with `isOrderedAndBounded x hi r`

Okay, this works. So how do we define `isOrdered` now? Well, it's simple, we just ask if a tree is ordered and bounded with no initial bounds... yeah, we don't have a way of doing that. Our function has no concept of "no bounds." There's multiple ways of dealing with this issue - you could define `isOrderedAndLeftBounded` and `isOrderedAndRightBounded` which take just a left and right bound, respectively, and then define `isOrdered` in terms of those, but I think that would be a bit too repetitive. Instead, I'm just going to make the bounds optional with `Maybe`:

```
isValueBounded :: Ord a => Maybe a -> Maybe a -> a -> Bool
isValueBounded (Just lo) _ x | x <= lo = False
isValueBounded _ (Just hi) x | hi <= x = False
isValueBounded _ _ _ = True

isOrderedAndBounded :: Ord a => Maybe a -> Maybe a -> Tree a -> Bool
isOrderedAndBounded _ _ Empty = True
isOrderedAndBounded lo hi (Node x l r) =
  isValueBounded lo hi x && isOrderedAndBounded lo (Just x) l && isOrderedAndBounded (Just x) hi r
```

Note that I've defined a little helper, `isValueBounded`, which checks if a value is within bounds, with both of those bounds being optional. `isOrderedAndBounded` stayed mostly the same, I've just replaced the bounds check with `isValueBounded` and I have to wrap the new bounds given by `x` in a `Just`, but that's about it.

Finally, all we need to define `isOrdered` is to just ask if a tree is bounded and ordered, but with the bounds being nonexistent:

```
isOrdered :: Ord a => Tree a -> Bool
isOrdered tree = isOrderedAndBounded Nothing Nothing tree
```

And there we go. That's six equations (with two guards) and no `if`s. Compared to the original 16 equations and 9 `if`s, I think that's a win. I think that `isValueBounded` could be written in a nicer way, but it'll do for now. Also, the time complexity should be linear in the number of nodes - we visit each node only once, which I don't think was the case for your code.

I hope this helps.

Edit: I've just now seen the other question that you've posted about this and I see that @chi has given you a similar suggestion. Oh well.